# Append string to future element after it will be loaded (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need something like this (for future loaded html to page!):

```
$(document).on('ready', 'a', function(){ $(this).after('it works'); });
```

This doesn't work (need similar event, like 'load' or 'ready' **to fire after element will be added to the page**). For example another event:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'a', function(){ $(this).after('it works'); });
```

working normaly. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "future element" here. Is it being loaded via ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably because these elements don't fire `onload` events. The `document`'s `load` event is fired after all elements have loaded, so you can try using that.

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'a', function(){ $(this).after('it works'); });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aajFc/1/)

Comment: you don't grasp the idea: need to add text to element after it will be created (each <a> element), even if it will be loaded dynamicly. Something like live().

Comment: Well, `ready` isn't an event fired by newly created elements. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will help, but try using .live

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: The use of `live` is not preferred anymore. `on` or `delegate` should be used instead.

Comment: live works with: change, submit, focus, blur, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, mouseup. No "ready" or "load" events. Also it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajaxComplete()? Or just CSS?

Comment: Ajax request not my, i can only monitor to the addition of new elements to the page.